# Python - Most efficient way to compare # of words sequenced in "right" order across two strings/lists

Tags: python, string, list, comparison, sequence

I was wondering what the most computationally efficient Python way of cracking this problem would be.

Say you have two strings (or lists from splitting those strings--doesn't matter), "this is the right string" vs. "this is right the string."

We're assuming that the first string is always right, and a score will be assigned to the second string based on which words were sequenced in the right order. For the above two strings, we would assign a score of 0.6 (as only 3 of the 5 words are in the right position).

Best,
Georgina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = "this is the right string"
b = "this is right the string"

sum([1 for i,v in zip(a.split(), b.split()) if i == v])
```

Comment: you don't needs list comprehension there

Comment: @SilentGhost: yes thanks, i should start thing more generator expression :)

Comment: @eumiro: i think the change is trivial isn't it ? beside helping some one with a problem don't mean give in him all the answer, just given some indication to the right answer can help him too

Comment: that's true. If OP is searching for 'computationally efficient' code, he could check itertools. But how to split() a string lazily?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds very much like homework. Try thinking about it for a bit. Would it suffice to traverse the list of correct words once, and check if the corresponding word in the second list is equal to the word in the correct list?

I would probably zip the lists in python and compare the pairs for equality.

Comment: It's easy to come up with *a* solution, but I'm looking for the fastest, most computationally efficient one!

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(f == s for f, s in zip(first, second)) / len(first)
```

Comment: In Python 2.x returns 0 because of the integer division. some `float()` could be needed.

Comment: @eumiro: might return 1 depending on the input

Comment: yes, might return 1. But in the OP's example should return 0.6 and returns 0.

Comment: @eumiro: it's completely besides the point. Accepter answer doesn't return 0.6 either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord()` to convert each character to an integer value (its ordinal value), and then XOR each character together using the bitwise operator `^`. If the characters are the same, the XOR operation will return `0` (zero), then use `|=` to bitwise OR the returned value with `result` and then save the result of the operation as `result`. If `result` is still zero after you iterate over all the characters, then the strings are equivalent.

```
a = "this is the right string"
b = "this is right the string"

result = 0
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    result |= ord(x) ^ ord(b)

(if result == 0): print "Equivalent"
```